# Ruby on Rails -- multiple selection in f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following select box in my form:

```
Related Type: &nbsp; <%= f.select(:TYPE, [['Type A', 'Type A'],
                                  ['Type B', 'Type B'],
                                  ['Type C', 'Type C'],
                                  ['Type D', 'Type D'],
                                  ['Type E', 'Type E']
                                 ],{ :prompt => "Please select"}
                                 ) %>
```

I want to allow the user to make multiple selections and also make the size of the select box 5.

How to do that for the code above?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

After your `{ :prompt => "Please select"}` add another hash with html options e.g.

```
<%= f.select(:TYPE, [['Type A', 'Type A'],
                                  ['Type B', 'Type B'],
                                  ['Type C', 'Type C'],
                                  ['Type D', 'Type D'],
                                  ['Type E', 'Type E']
                                 ],{ :prompt => "Please select"},
                                   { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }
                                 ) %>
```

Once you've done this you might want to move your `:prompt` option (keep the empty `{}` though so that html attributes don't get treated as Rails options.)

Also you'll need to ensure your controller code is correctly accepting and handling multiple values.

Comment: Why does this add "---" and "-" for every non-selected option that's stored in :TYPE?

Comment: When i save it in form it takes an extra empty "" at position 0

"ids" => [ [0] "",
            [1] "some_id" ]

Answer (score 11):

In case of collection, try

```
    <%= f.select(:TYPE, Categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, 
                                           { :prompt => "Please select"}, 
                                           { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }) %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Category.all.collect`?

Answer (score 10):

I have a fully working example (including preselection when editing the object), when:

- `Object` is the considered object
- `similar_ids` is the key to relations, and is a `string`

In the form:

```
form_for(@object) do |f|
  = f.select :similar_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Object.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @object.similar_ids.split(';')}), {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 4, :name => 'object[similar_ids][]'}
```

And in the `Object.rb` model:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :handle_similars

  def handle_similars
    self.similar_ids = self.similar_ids.select(&:present?).join(';') 
    # .select(&:present?) is necessary to avoid empty objects to be stored
  end

  def similars
    self.class.find(self.similar_ids.split(';'))
  end

end
```

These posts helped me out:

- [Select tag with multiple values pre-selected - Values inserted manually in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667251/select-tag-with-multiple-values-pre-selected-values-inserted-manually-in-datab)
- [Ruby on Rails: Submitting an array in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form)

Hope it helps

Comment: It's important that the name ends in `[]` so that rails interprets the params as an array of values

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<%= form.select(:product_ids, Product.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, 
                                                   { :prompt => "Please select"}, 
                                                   { :multiple => true, :size => 5  }) %>
```

Controller

```
@category = Category.new(category_params) 

def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, product_ids: [])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ :prompt => "Please select"}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5 } {}
```

is important when `f.select`

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap selectpicker and pre selected values:

```rb
    = simple_form_for [:backend, @user], html: { autocomplete: 'off' } do |f|
      = f.select :role_ids, options_for_select(Role.all.map{|role| [role.name, role.id]}, @user.role_ids), {},  {:multiple => true, include_blank: false, class: "form-control input-sm selectpicker"}
```

in controller:

```rb
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, role_ids: [])
end

# only if you havent build in new action
def new
  # set user
  @user.roles.any?
end
```

Comment: just a heads up, there is a typo in `inlcude_blank`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple select:

```
= form_with url: ui_dashboard_diagrams_path, method: :get, local: true do |f|
  .row
    .col.form-group
      = f.select :our_organization_ids,
                 options_for_select(OurOrganization.pluck(:name, :id), params[:our_organization_ids]),
                 { include_blank: '' },
                 { multiple: true, class: 'form-control form-select-multiple' }


javascript:
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-select-multiple').select2({
      allowClear: true,
      multiple: true
    });
  });
```

Add permit array `our_organization_ids` to your controller:

```
private

def diagrams_params
  params.permit([our_organization_ids: []])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the solutions above, I also had to change the name of the input, so Rails will parse the parameters as array. here the input created with simple form:

```rb
= f.input :my_ids, collection: ['A', 'B'], include_blank: false, input_html: { name: 'form[my_ids][]', multiple: 'multiple' }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.select :tag_ids, Tag.all.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, { :prompt => "Please select"}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5 } %>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation so the OP and future readers will know why and how your code solves the problem at hand.