# Adding class to Rails select form helper, and multiple selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I am trying to add a class to the select form helper, here is my code:

```
<%= f.select :manager_id, user.collect {|u| [u.username, u.id]}, :prompt => "Select manager 
username", :class => "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" %>
```

But it didn't work, and is there an option to add multiple selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the curly brackets for the hash. class is part of the last parameter. If you don't add the brackets, it goes as third

```
<%= f.select :manager_id, user.collect {|u| [u.username, u.id]}, {:prompt => "Select manager 
username"}, {:class => "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", :multiple => true} %>
```

I haven't tried the multiple option in select. But it should work according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864513/ruby-on-rails-multiple-selection-in-f-select)

Comment: Could you please also answer the multiple selection part of the question.

Comment: Modified my answer. I haven't personally tried it though