# Select tag with multiple values pre-selected - Values inserted manually in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to pre-select multiple values in a select_tag. But I'm adding the vacancies 'manually' in table vacancies as follows:

My controller:

```
def create
  @hr_curriculum_generic = HrCurriculumGeneric.new(params[:hr_curriculum_generic])

  if params[:vacancy_ids].present?
    @vacancies_ids = params[:vacancy_ids]
```

-- my form:

```
  @vacancies_ids.each do |vacancy_id|
    # Armazena os id do curriculum, vaga e do cargo na tabela CandidatosxVagas
    @candidates_vacancies = CandidatesVacancy.new 
    <% @vacancies = Vacancy.all %>
    <%= select_tag "vacancy_ids[]", options_from_collection_for_select(Vacancy.all, "id", "title"), :multiple => true, :id => "vacancy_ids", :class => "form-control" %>
```

.....

It works, but when I click in the edit btn, the fields are not being pre-selected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) has 4 parameters:

- collection
- id
- column
- selected

You can provide a single value, or a hash to denote selected values. Try this:

```
<%= select_tag "vacancy_ids[]", options_from_collection_for_select(Vacancy.all,"id","title",{:selected=>[1,2,3,4]})), :multiple => true, :id => "vacancy_ids", :class => "form-control" %>
```

I'm not sure where the values you are trying to select come from but pipe them into the selected hash.