# Rails Form: f.select for multiple options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For my user form, I have a hobbies drop-down menu and I want to be able to select more than one option (one user may have skiing, reading, and chess as hobbies).

Of course, doing this is very [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864513/ruby-on-rails-multiple-selection-in-f-select)!

However, none of the available options seem to work for me...

Here's my code:

```
<%= f.select :hobbies, [['Chess','chess'],
                        ['Movies','movies'],
                        ['Videogames','videogames'],
                        ['Skiing', 'skiing'],
                        ['Reading','reading']],
                        {:multiple => true} %>
```

However, when I look at my form, I don't think this is working. It makes the drop-down menu....but how do I select multiple entries? I try ctr + click but it doesn't do anything....what am I missing? It keeps just selecting one value only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the accepted answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864801/3012550) - the method signature is:

```
select(:type, [data], {options hash}, {second options hash})
```

And in the answer, it has `multiple: true` in the second options hash.

[API dock for `select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) gives a hint about what the two different hashes are for - it looks like the first options hash is for "option_tags", and the second one is for "options"

Comment: The important thing to remember here is that if a function has multiple hash arguments, you must encapsulate your arguments within curly braces in order to separate them. `select(type, data, options, {options})` will ignore the final hash argument whereas `select(type, data, {options}, {options})` will not