# Collection_select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to know how I can make a  with multiple select in ruby on rails.

for example:

I have this

`<% b.label :question %>`

```html
<select multiple class="question">
  <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat bad">Cat</option>
  <option value="Rabbit">Rabbit</option>
</select>
```

the idea is like to create a field but I don't want the user write the answer, only a I want they choose the answer or multiple answer if the want.

Thank You so much.

Comment: You can see something like you want to do please have a look at [here ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864801/5922155)

Comment: You can see something like you want to do please have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4864801/5922155)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select_tag` method (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag). So you can do something like:

```
select_tag "question", options_for_select([["Dog", "Dog"], ["cat bad", "Cat"], ["Rabbit", "Rabbit"]])
```