# Ruby on Rails form isn't capturing values in select multiple field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, erb

I followed the example here to create a select multiple element for my form: [Ruby on Rails -- multiple selection in f.select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864513/ruby-on-rails-multiple-selection-in-f-select)

However, when the submit button is clicked the values from the select field are not captured. I had the same issue when using checkboxes. It works when I change it to a text field, though. Am I missing something obvious? How do I capture the values that the user selects from the select field? My code is below.

The form: new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @service do |f| %>
<div class="row">
          <h3>Operating hours</h3>
          <p>Please select the days you are open. Hold CTRL (Windows) or Command (Mac) to select multiple.</p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <%= f.select(:work_days, [['Monday', 'Monday'],
                              ['Tuesday', 'Tuesday'],
                              ['Wednesday', 'Wednesday'],
                              ['Thursday', 'Thursday'],
                              ['Friday', 'Friday'],
                              ['Saturday', 'Saturday'],
                              ['Sunday', 'Sunday']
                             ],{},
                               { :multiple => true, :size => 7 }
                             ) %>
            </div> <!--  .col-md-6 -->
          </div>  <!-- .form-group -->
        </div> <!-- .row -->

        <!-- the code in the div below works -->
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="work_days">work days</label>
                  <%= f.text_field :work_days, placeholder: "Type the days you are available", class: "form-control", required: true, id: "work_days" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> <!-- .row  -->

        <div class="text-center">
          <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>

      <% end %>
```

The relevant controller code: services_controller.rb

```
 class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  # require the user to be logged in to edit and create, but not to view
  before_action :set_service, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:listing, :update]

  def new
    @service = current_user.services.build
  end

  def create
    @service = current_user.services.build(service_params)
    if @service.save
      redirect_to listing_service_path(@service), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
      render :new
    end
  end


  private
    def set_service
      @service = Service.find(params[:id])
    end


    def service_params
        params.require(:service).permit(:title, :description, :work_days, :open_time, :close_time)
    end
end
```

Comment: You won't be able to save multiple work_days to the DB unless you are using a Postgres array column or accept nested attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `service_params`, `work_days` should accept an array so it will accept multiple values:

```
def service_params
  params.require(:service).permit(
    :title,
    :description,
    :open_time,
    :close_time,
    work_days: []
  )
end
```