# In a Rails form, how to add a multiselect dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a Rails form which includes a dropdown as shown below:

```rb
    <%= f.select :facility_id, options_for_select(@entities.collect{ |e| [e.entity, e.entity] }, 1 ), {include_blank: '-Select-'}, { id: my_entity'} %>
```

I also have 2 more dropdowns similar to the one above.

1. I would like to make the above dropdown as a multiselect dropdown. How can I achieve that?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just need to add this to the tag
    `{ :multiple => true}`
like this

```
<%= f.select :facility_id, options_for_select(@entities.collect{ |e| [e.entity, e.entity] }, 1 ), {prompt: '-Select-', :multiple => true}, { id: my_entity'} %>
```

Comment: That seems to work. Quick question though pls? How can I select multiple entries in this dropdown from the UI?

Comment: Using shift key or control key while select

Comment: Thanks much. I made a syntax mistake and hence the I was not able to select multiple items. It's fixed now. Sorry about the dumb question.

I have raised another related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746270/in-rails-dropdown-how-to-display-all-column-names-from-a-model

Would you mind taking a look please? Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `multiple: true` in `select`

Example:

```
<%= f.select :facility_id, options_for_select(@entities.collect{ |e| [e.entity, e.entity] }, 1 ), {include_blank: '-Select-'}, { id: my_entity'}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5 } %>
```

Reference: [[1]](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864513/ruby-on-rails-multiple-selection-in-f-select)