# In Rails dropdown, how to display all column names from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a Rails dropdown as shown below:

```rb
<%= select_tag(:category, options_for_select([['Model1', 0], ['Model2', 1], ['Model3', 2], ['Model4', 3]], :selected => 0), :multiple => true) %>
```

By default `Model1` would be selected as shown above. Each item in the dropdown above is a Rails model (which obviously has its own database table)

1. Now, I would like to display another dropdown which would display all the column names from the Rails model `Model1`'s table.
2. If the user changes the selection to `Model2` in the dropdown above, then the second dropdown should display all the column names from `Model2`.
3. If the user selects multiple options from the above, then I would like to display columns from all the models which the user had selected.

How can I achieve that please?

Comment: Those are too many requirements for a single question, no?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, [ActiveRecord#column_names](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class) is the way to populate your second dropdown.

Now, if what you want is a dynamic relation between two dropdowns - the second being filled with information depending on the first one - Rails alone will not be enough.

You will need to add a bit of javascript to achieve that goal and I suggest you read that [answer by @rlarcombe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33734368/637898) on the matter.