# Ruby On Rails: How do I create multple text_field_tags that store the values into the same array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to create a form where there are several text_field_tags that are created dynamically depending on the instances of another model. I want to be able to store the values that are entered into these text_field_tags into the same array that I can access as a parameter in the controller once the form is submitted. Is this possible?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form) for an example of what (I think) you're after.

Comment: this was useful for me when I did not have a model-backed form. I had a highly dynamic form (through jQuery) with 1 - many text fields but wanted more structure in my `params`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you give them all the same name and append [] to the end as follows:

```
 <%= text_field_tag "some_fields[]" %>
 <%= text_field_tag "some_fields[]" %>
 <%= text_field_tag "some_fields[]" %>
```

You can access these from the controller:

```
  some_fields = params[:some_fields] # this is an array
```

If you enter values between the square brackets, rails will view it as a hash:

```
 <%= text_field_tag "some_fields[1]" %>
 <%= text_field_tag "some_fields[2]" %>
 <%= text_field_tag "some_fields[3]" %>
```

would be interpreted by the controller as a hash with keys "1", "2" and "3"

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to do but apparently when I named the array arguments[], I was getting errors.

Comment: If you mix and match the array and hash syntax you will get an error.