# Submitting an array in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been reading this question ([Ruby on Rails: Submitting an array in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form)) but it didn't answer my question.

I have this form:

```
<div class="signup pull-right">                        
  <div>                                                
   <p style="color: white">Create Doctor:</p>           
   <%= form_for(@doctor) do |d| %>                      
     <%= d.text_field :name[1], :placeholder => "name" %>                                                      
     <%= d.text_field :name[2], :placeholder => "surname" %>                                                   
     <%= d.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email" %>
     <%= d.text_field :password, :placeholder => "password" %>                                                 
     <%= d.text_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "password confirmation" %>                      

    <%= d.submit "Sumbit", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right", id: "boton" %>                      
  <% end %>                                            
 </div>
```

where name is an array. What I want is to catch name and surname separately and join them inside name[]. I couldn't found the way to do it easily. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check till I have this html generated:

```
<input name='doctor[name][]'>
```

I would try:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'doctor[name][]' %>
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, but it doesn't solve it.. What you mean exactly with the "names I mention"? :name or :email?

Comment: jeje was weird. Forget that part. How is HTML being generated with each option I posted?

Comment: Juan, i lied you, sorry. This is exactly what i need. It solved my problem (8 hours late....). I'm newbie. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can mark this as accepted then...by the way I was just passing and saw your comment... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such hack to solve the problem. Setting the attributes by virtual `cattr_accessor` would be simple and conventional.

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :first_name, :surname
  # others...
end
```

Then in form

```
<%= form_for(@doctor) do |d| %>                      
 <%= d.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "first name" %>
 <%= d.text_field :surname, :placeholder => "surname" %>
```

Then in controller

```
def create
  attr = params[:doctor]
  attr[:name] = "#{attr.delete!(:first_name)} #{attr.delete!(:surname)}"
  @doctor = Doctor.new(attr)
  if @doctor.save
    # blah blah
end
```

Comment: why cattr_accesor and not attr_accessor? could you explain?

Comment: @juanpastas, in this case they should be the same as we only need the attributes to work on instance level. Both can do that. I just get used to `cattr_accessor` which is a Rails method but not a Ruby one.