# Using Arrays in Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Using Rails 4.1.5 and simple_form, 3.0.2 and Postgresql, I have declared an array, rsvp_options in the functions table. Following stAndres [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form), I did the following

```
<%= simple_form_for @function do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :rsvp_options, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.input_field :rsvp_options, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit , class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>
```

If @function.rsvp_options is initalised with ['test1','test2'], then simple form displays two boxes, but both ones have {'test1','test2'} in them.  If @function.rsvp_options is initialised with [], then both boxes have {} in them. Also, there is no label for the boxes.

Apart from this, simple_form actually works, in the sense that if I put text into each box, then the rsvp_options variable is updated properly. In other words, the only problem is with the display of the information, not the handling of it into params.

So, how do I use simpleform to properly display the array data and also give a label for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [open issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1124) would seem to indicate that simple_form does not support arrays at the present time.