# Working with postgreSQL arrays in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have Rails 5 app. And lets say I have this table (PG ORM):

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.text :tags, array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'd like to see in my form text input with separated by commas tags. And when I hit 'save' button Rails would properly save it in array field. How can I do it?

Comment: You have to make comma separated string manually.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the array in the form you can do this:

## Eg multiple input fields all with the same name:

```
<input type="textbox" name="course[track_codes][]" ...>
```

## will become the Array

```
params["course"]["track_codes"]
```

## with an element for each of the input fields with the same name

Check answer: [Ruby on Rails: Submitting an array in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form)

Also if you are using simple_form, then you can do this:

```
form_for @location do |f|
  f.input :zips, as: :array
end
```