# Rails migration of an array inside a model doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rails-migrations

I am trying to create a model with some arrays inside it. After creating the migration file by this command:

```
rails g model post poster_first_name:string poster_first_name:string email:string poster_id:integer poster_profile_pic:string message:string post_type:string comments:text
```

The migration file is created and I modify the migration file to look like this (trying to make the `post_type` and `comments` arrays):

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.integer :poster_id,        null: false, default: 0
      t.string :poster_first_name,              default: ""
      t.string :poster_last_name,               default: ""
      t.string :poster_profile_pic,             default: ""
      t.string :message,           null: false, default: ""
      t.string :post_type,         array: true, default: []
      t.text :comments,            array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This migration file looks correct. After I run `rake db:migrate`

This is how my schema looks:

```
 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer  "poster_id",          default: 0,          null: false
   t.string   "poster_first_name",  default: ""
   t.string   "poster_last_name",   default: ""
   t.string   "poster_profile_pic", default: ""
   t.string   "message",            default: "",         null: false
   t.string   "post_type",          default: "--- []\n"
   t.text     "comments",           default: "--- []\n"
   t.datetime "created_at",                              null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                              null: false
 end
```

So basically rails doesn't understand that the fields are arrays. I have tried a lot of different stuff. But no luck. I would appreciate any help.
(This might be a noob question)

Comment: What is the Rails version that you are using?

Comment: My rails version: Rails 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer: [Ruby on Rails: Submitting an array in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089849/ruby-on-rails-submitting-an-array-in-a-form)

So you can understand how to use it.